# Ruby Gem Dialog

Tags: ruby, dialog, rubygems

I'm trying to use the ruby `dialog` [gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/dialog). It seems to throw some syntax errors, particularly from `when` statments that use a colon after the conditional.

```
when File: f.path
```

Was this syntax that was used in earlier versions of ruby, or another error entirely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This gem is pretty old (March 28, 2008) probably written by times where ruby 1.8 was used. You're probably using ruby >= 1.9, which does not allow you to use case statement like this (with colons). If you want to use this gem you'd probably need to switch to ruby 1.8.

Comment: I figured that might be the case, which is why I thought I would ask. Already sent a note to the developer to see if there could be an update.